# Is a linux question for FPGA on-topic?

Tags: support, asking-questions, specific-question

I want to know how and if and when / where the run linux if possible with my FPGA (Altera DE2). Can I ask about it here or should there be another forum for that question?

### Update

I asked it on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644348/can-uclinux-run-on-the-altera-de2-115

Comment: Do you mean making an FPGA run linux or using linux to develop for an FPGA?

Comment: "run linux .. with my FPGA" makes me think he wants to host embedded linux on the FPGA, which would probably fall under embedded design.

Comment: The ability to run linux on something is ultimately nothing more than a question of having sufficient RAM, and of course the necessary hardware documentation to create the port.  In the specific case, the best source would be the documentation of whatever existing port (presumably the NIOS 2 given the mentioned FPGA brand) is contemplated, rather than *any* of the stack exchange sites.

Comment: I mean making an FPGA run Linux. I asked it on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644348/can-uclinux-run-on-the-altera-de2-115